# Scanner driver for a Camera Stream (or IP Camera)

Tags: camera, ip, driver

I would like to use my IP Camera as a real scanner.

The question is :
is it possible ( or is this type of driver already exists ) to have a real driver (TWAIN, WLA, ...) for a generic IP Camera (MJEPG or H264 stream)
which instead of scanning and preview, take one snapshot from this camera and offers some classic tools (like resizing, cropping, contrast, light level ?) 
Basically I search a Windows / MacOS solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your IP Camera supports TWAIN, then it should be easy to develop your own application (I'm guessing that's what you're asking since you're asking this in Stack Overflow) that takes an image from the camera using TWAIN and then perform the image operations that you wanted (resize, crop, etc.).

I recommend using [Python](https://www.python.org/) with the [pytwain / twain](https://github.com/denisenkom/pytwain) module for this. You can code a very quick prototype to see if it works with your IP Camera. Then you can use [OpenCV Python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) or [Pillow (PIL)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to perform the image processing and image operations. This solution is also cross platform (should work in Windows / Mac OS / Linux) which is what you also wanted.

Comment: Thanks Yes... My camera is the Raspberry PI Camera in IP mode ... so I don't know if this Camera supports TWAIN but ... I have to test it !!